# Automatic booting of SunOS 4.1.14 in qemu-system-sparc: OpenFirmware vs OpenBIOS

Tags: qemu, solaris, sunos

In a fit of nostalgia I decided to boot SunOS 4.1.4 up under emulation using `qemu-system-sparc`. It all seems to work, but I'm trying to remove an annoying manual step.

I'm starting `qemu-system-sparc` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec qemu-system-sparc \
    -rtc base=2009-12-13 \
    -drive file=sunos-root.img,format=raw,bus=0,unit=3 \
    -drive file=sunos-home.img,format=raw,bus=0,unit=1 \
    -nographic \
    -bios ss5.bin \
    "$@"
```

This boots the root disk at SCSI target 3, which matches the Open Firmware devalias for disk:

```
ok devalias disk
disk           /iommu/sbus/espdma@5,8400000/esp@5,8800000/sd@3,0
```

Unfortunately, when booting with an Open Firmware ROM (like [this one](https://github.com/andarazoroflove/sparc/blob/master/ss5.bin)), something insists on setting the `diag-switch?` setting to `true` when the system boots:

```
Incorrect configuration checksum;
Setting NVRAM parameters to default values.
Setting diag-switch? NVRAM parameter to true
```

That means the system tries (and fails) to boot from the network, dropping to the `ok` prompt, which requires me to type `boot disk` to actually boot the system.

If I drop the SparcStation 5 ROM (i.e. get rid of the `-bios ss5.bin` option), the system boots using OpenBIOS instead, which has a different problem: apparently the `disk` alias in OpenBIOS doesn't point at target 3:

```
0 > boot disk Not a bootable ELF image
Not a bootable a.out image
No valid state has been set by load or init-program
 ok
0 > boot disk1 Not a bootable ELF image
Loading a.out image...
Loaded 7680 bytes
entry point is 0x4000
```

Unexpectedly, the magic name is `disk1`.

So, I have a questions:

- Is there any way to resolve the `Incorrect configuration checksum` message that shows up when using Open Firmware? I suspect that would allow the system to boot correctly.
- Aternatively, is there any way to get OpenBIOS to boot from `disk1` by default? You'd think that adding `-prom-env boot-device=disk1` would do it, but that doesn't work.

Comment: It is an excellent question that makes sense to someone like me who knows nothing about the subject matter.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

I know of a few people doing this, or at least things much like it. I have found a few links, in case they help.

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/SunOS_4.1.4
- http://defcon.no/sysadm/playing-with-sunos-4-1-4-on-qemu/
- found via https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/2013/12/05/qemu-sunos-4-1-4/
- or in case you like videos: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x216hbh

Any of these any help at all?

If not, I would suggest asking on the SunRescue or ClassicCmp.org mailing lists.

Comment: How about the source code to SunOS 4.1.4? You can search the IA for it.